# Check schema compatibility with API giving permission denied error

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use below command to check the compatibility of my schema against the latest on in kafka

```
curl -s username:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
  --data '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"}' \
  http://localhost:8081/compatibility/subjects/Kafka-value/versions/latest
```

I expect an output telling it is compatible or not, but instead I get the below error

```
{"error_code":40301,"message":"User is denied operation Write on Subject: my-service-topic-value"}
```

I may not have permission to update the schema, but is it required to check the compatibility?

Comment: HTTP basic auth should cover all endpoints, yes.